# Converting Excel Range in Variable in Python

Tags: python, arrays, excel, variables

I am trying to read stock tickers in Excel and would like to attribute them to the x variable, so we do not have to modify the code everytime we change the stocks tickers. But instead we would simply modify the CSV file. is there a simple way please? 
The data are located in A1 (JPM), A2 (GS), A3(C) in the Excel turned CSV.

```
url = '/Users/Mood/Documents/SIAF_PYTHON/SINOAF_BETA/SIAF_STOCK_SOURCE.csv'
k = pd.read_csv(url,usecols=[0])
k[0:3]
ticker =('JPM','GS','C')
```

Comment: Please add an example of your data and example of what you want.

Comment: Hi Dawg, Instead of putting ticker = ('JPM','GS','C'), I would like something like ticker = k.

Comment: What does the source data look like?

Comment: It is actually and Excel file with JPM in Cell A1, GS in cell A2 and C in cell A3. But ultimately it will have 1000s cells